# Windows not booting after deleting hiberfile.sys

Tags: windows-10, boot, ntfs, hibernate, ntfs-3g

I had problems with my SSD and I had to check and repair the disk through a Linux live USB. To do it I encountered the problem it could not run fsck because of windows hibernation, so I deleted the hiberfile with

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile
```

Disk repair went successfully then, but when I try to reboot my windows 10 it fails with error code `0xc000000f`.

What happened? What can I do to repair windows without having to download their ISO again?

Comment: Fails how, with what error message?

Comment: Your issue booting into Windows has less to do with the fact you deleted the hibernation file, which when removed, would result in a normal boot and more to do with the reasons you had to run fsck to begin with.  In other words, it's unlikely Windows would have been able to boot, even with the hibernation file.

Comment: As additional comment, "fixing" Windows disks via Linux has a good chance of ending with a disaster. I hope you took good backups of your data, but if not do so via Linux asap.

Comment: If the drive was not cleanly unmounted and you forced an fsck this would also likely lead to filesystem corruption. Any solution is going to involve downloading their ISO again. At the very minimum you need to the media to run the windows repair utility.

Comment: Updated with error code

Comment: Unfortunately disk was damaged and if I tried to power off it from windows to run chdsk at startup, it just stayed stuck on shutdown screen forever, if forced to shutdown with power button it would just restart windows without doing the chkdsk. Only solution I could think of was logging into my Linux Live and try to repair the disk from there.

Comment: @Kodeeo: what's the download speed of your internet? The Windows 10 (x64) ISO is only 3.88 GB and takes ~7 minutes to download (provided your download speed is 90 Mbps or faster); I just tested it myself. It's much quicker to download the ISO than to spend hours trying to find a workaround. Personally, I would try a repair using the Windows 10 installer and if that didn't work, I would back up any data to another drive and do a clean install of Windows. It's a very quick process. If the SSD fails S.M.A.R.T. monitoring and/or has problems after you reinstall Windows 10 then I would replace it.

Comment: I'm in Italy, not in a big city. My max download speed here is almost 5mbit/s, so it's pretty slow to download 4 or more GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0xc000000f error on startup means that the bootloader did not find the
BCD file, which is the database for all boot-related options and settings.

Although there are methods for fixing the BCD, I would rather suggest to
create a new Windows installation media on another healthy Windows 10
computer, and use it to repair the startup code.

For details see the article
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

There is no guarantee the disk can be made as good as it was before the
problem happened. I would suggest to have a look at the SMART data of the
disk to see if the disk has suffered a catastrophic error and should be
replaced.

I would suggest first, before doing anything else, to use Linux to backup
all data for which you don't already have backups.